# How can I move only the files that are *not* in list.txt?

Tags: macos, bash, unix

I have a list of filenames of .jpg files. I would like to move all images out of a given filetree except those in the list. I've been trying to use a find loop to do this, but it doesn't quite work:

```
x=$(find . -type f -not -name "$line")
while IFS= read -r line ; do
mv "$x" Destination/
done < Filenames.txt
```

Excerpt from Filenames.txt:

```
IMG_5253 (2).jpg
IMG_5255 (2).jpg
IMG_5256 (2).jpg
IMG_3988.JPG
IMG_3989.JPG
IMG_3990.JPG
```

I think I can see why this is problematic (I don't really want a loop, exactly), but I can't see how to fix it. What's a good way to do this?

*Edit*: Rsync worked for me, with help from @ghoti and this thread: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76237/rsync-certain-files-excluding-the-rest-ignoring-svn-directory-recursively

```
rsync -rv --exclude-from '/Path/To/Filename.txt' --exclude='*Pattern/For/Other/Files/That/Should/Stay/Put*' --include='*.jpg' --include='*.JPG' --include='*/' --exclude="*" --remove-source-files Path/To/Source Path/To/Destination
```

I also had great luck with the Perl solution posted below, and it ran very fast by comparison to some of the other options. I marked rsync as my solution since that's what I used, but others coming after might want to look at @Tom_Fenench's solution too.

Comment: I think the best way to do this probably involves a script in a more powerful language such as perl or python.

Comment: Please add content of Filenames.txt to your question.

Comment: Updated answer based on comment feedback

Comment: Do you have access to GNU tar?

Comment: @Cyrus - if you're thinking of GNU tar's `--exclude-from` option, I'll point out for posterity that this option also exists in FreeBSD's `tar` as well (though it's a recent enough addition that it hasn't made it over to OSX yet).

Comment: @Cyrus I don't think so, I'm on a mac using bsdtar.

Comment: @ghoti: Yes, with GNU tar this is possible: `tar --exclude-from=/path/to/exclude/file --remove-files -C /path/to/source/dir -c . | tar -C /path/to/target/dir -xv`

Comment: Hmm, I believe OSX includes `rsync`, so you might be able to do something equivalent with: `rsync --exclude-from=/path/to/list.txt /sourcedir/ /targetdir/`.

Comment: Thanks @ghoti, rsync solved it for me. I borrowed some of the principles from here: [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76237/rsync-certain-files-excluding-the-rest-ignoring-svn-directory-recursively), which was handy since I had other non-JPG files in the directory that I didn't want to move out. I wound up with this: `rsync -rv --exclude-from '/Path/To/Filename.txt' --exclude='*Other/Files/That/Stay/Put*' --include='*.jpg' --include='*.JPG' --include='*/' --exclude="*" --remove-source-files Path/To/Source Path/To/Destination`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't fast, but it should work.

```
find /startpath  -name \*.jpg -not -exec grep -q '^{}$' filenames.txt \; -exec mv -v {} /target/path/
```

This will start in `/startpath`, then drill through all subdirectories looking for files that end in `.jpg`. For each one of these, it will run a `grep` of your file, and if that grep is `-not` successful, will print the filename as it moves it in a second `-exec`.

Note that because of the way `find` matches things, you may need to prepend filenames with paths, even if those paths are `./`.

Note also that this is NOT a speed- or IO-optimized solution, as it launches a separate `grep` command for each file it finds.

Alternately, if you want to use `rsync`, you could do so with something like this:

```
rsync -a -v --exclude-from=/path/to/list.txt --remove-source-files /sourcedir/ /targetdir/
```

Comment: Cool, this looks promising. Will it work for filenames with spaces?

Comment: The nice thing about using `find` is that it handles *anything* in the conversion of `{}` to a filename, including control characters like newlines. To handle special characters, you should probably put `{}` inside quotes though -- not for `find` of course, but for `mv`.

Comment: This gets close, but it appears to move everything out, whether it's in the list or not. I added quotes to `{}` for mv, and I added a `\;` at the end. Here's the code I'm using: `find /Path/To/Images -name \*.jpg -not -exec grep -q '^{}$' Filenames.txt \; -exec mv -v "{}" 
/Path/To/Destination \;`

Comment: The issue is almost certainly that your filenames in `list.txt` are not specified with the path exactly the same as `find` matches them. To see what `find` needs, try using a `-print` instead of the second `-exec`. Compare the output to what's in `list.txt`.

Comment: Makes sense, but I can't figure out how to solve for this. `find` is printing full paths, so that's probably what it's trying to match. Filenames.txt only lists filenames, not paths, so there's no matching happening at all. The output prints as though the whole command was `find /Path/To/Images -name \*.jpg`.

Comment: To solve this, you would need to update `list.txt` with the full paths of the files, in the same format as displayed by the `-print` option. I've added my rsync suggestion to this answer, in case you want to use that as a reason to resolve your question. :)

Comment: I want to say that `find` can absolutely work in this case, and if he has thousands and thousands on images that the command line cant expand with the command he absolutely needs to use `find` or some higher level language.  However, my problem with `find` is the OS will iterate through absolutely everything looking for what OP wanted.  Its like using a sledgehammer to a nail together bird house.  I mean, yeah, it will definitely do its job, but its my belief that are better options for small scale operations.  This is just my opinion.

Comment: And a +1 for precision sledgehammer art. :-) IMHO, this is *exactly* the sort of thing that `find` was designed for.

Comment: You still need to `basename` all the found items to exclude a file given in Filenames.txt in all folders. For the art-lovers a slow-motion sledgehammer.
To speed-up: first collect all jpg-files, `grep -v` the files in Filenames.txt and move the resulting files (using `xargs`?).

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way that you could solve your problem using Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;    
use File::Find;
use File::Copy;

my %files;
open my $fh, "<", "Filenames.txt";
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    $files{$_}++;
}

sub wanted {
    if (-f && /\.jpg$/ && !exists $files{$_}) {
        move($_, "/path/to/destination");
    }
}
find(\&wanted, ".");
```

It reads the file names from `Filenames.txt` and uses them to build a hash `%files`. It then searches recursively in the current directory, executing the subroutine `wanted` for everything it finds. It moves every file that ends in `.jpg` and isn't found in the hash into the destination directory `path/to/destination` (it is assumed that this directory already exists).

It's important to make sure that the destination is outside of the tree, otherwise it will interfere with the search.

Comment: Thanks! Personally w would I prefer ruby or python, but I would graciously accept one in DWIM script  (e.g. the Do What I Mean shell :-) ).

Comment: You're welcome, although I'm a little confused about who was asking the question!

Comment: This appears to work very well. FYI for anyone following along, the .pl file has to live in the top directory of the filetree in question.

Comment: FYI this solution moves *all* files out. Any thoughts on how to limit it to moving just .jpg files? I also had to change `"../out"` to an absolute path, else the script creates a file called `out` in the directory directly above every subdirectory it curses through, if that makes sense.

Comment: @two2the8 I edited the answer so that it only moves files ending in `.jpg`. Your point about the relative directory is correct; a simple solution is to use an absolute path as you suggested. Alternatively you can specify an option `no_chdir` to `find` like this: `find({wanted => \&wanted, no_chdir => 1}, ".");` (unfortunately I can't test this at the moment).

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer based on @Sorpigal comment below:

```
while IFS= read -d '' -r file ; do
    mv "$file" Destination/
done < <(find . -type f -print0 | grep -ZzFfv Filenames.txt)
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it relies on all of the file names being very well-behaved; even a space in one of them would cause it to break.

Comment: No. Don't change IFS. Don't use `for` over file names returned from a subshell! You also would want `fgrep` to avoid accidental pattern matching.

Comment: @nerdistcolony: Breaks certain file names. For safety do this: `while IFS= read -d ''-r file  ; do ... done < <(find . -type f -print0 | grep -ZzFfv Filenames.txt)`

Comment: @nerdistcolony: I have [created an example](http://www.fraglimit.net/~collin/stuff/for-subshell-files) to show the problems.

Comment: Syntax error: `JPGScript: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
JPGScript: line 5: `done < <(find . -type f -print0 | grep -ZzFfv /Path/To/Filenames.txt)'`

Comment: That's verbatim from @Sorpigal. I already deleted my test directory. Are you sure you're using an update full featured bash script? What is JPGScript?  If it's broken, maybe you or Sorpigal can fix it and edit the answer with the working solution and I'll accept it.

Comment: @two3the8 The <() construct is not understood by all shells, your bang line would need to specify bash. To debug further I'd want to see a pastebin of the entire script you're running.

Answer (score 0):

I believe using `find` in this case is too unwieldy.  I would recommend the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
dest=/fully/qualified/destination
# run this script in the directory with all your .jpg files
for filename in *.jpg; do
    if grep -q "$filename" Filenames.txt
    then
            #echo "Found file $filename in Filenames.txt, will do nothing"
    else
            #echo "Did not find file $filename in Filenames.txt, will move unwanted file"
            mv "$filename" $dest
    fi
done
```

I think your solution with `find` is only useful if you have thousands and thousands of file names in the same directory to the point where the command line cannot expand all of the entries, which is a different problem altogether.

If you have this many files in on directory, then I would agree with Tom, you should use a more powerful language, or use find `find`.

Comment: I don't think there's anything in this script that is bash-only. Why not use `/bin/sh` instead, for greater portability?  Also, you might want to quote your variables. A space in a filename would break your`grep` and your  `mv`.

Comment: Also, I'd love to get your comments on [my `find` solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32958831/1072112). I don't see it as unwieldy, but I'm eager to learn why it might be!  Seems to me that it does the same thing as your shell script, only all within `find`.

Comment: This looks good, but my files are in various directories, so I would like to be able to do this recursively. Thoughts? Can I do something like `for filename in *.jpg **/*.jpg ; do`?

Comment: @two2the8, yes, `**/*.jpg` notation requires `shopt -s globstar` in bash.  Or you can use `find`, which also recurses through subdirectories by default.

Comment: @ghoti Because I whipped the script up in 2 minutes, but you are right. On all points.  I will update my post.

Comment: @two2the8 If this is just a one off process, you could just copy and paste the code above and then just change the directory to where the images are to `/directory1/*.jpg`.....copy paste.....`/directory2/*.jpg`.....copy paste and so on.   Its not elegant or even that proper, but my understanding is you just want these file moved and this isnt a long term solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think your filenames can have spaces but no newlines.
With newlines the layout of Filenames.txt can be problematic.
When all pictures are in one dir (assume images), you can do without find:

```
comm -23  <(ls -1 images) <(sort Filenames.txt) | while read file; do
   mv images/"$file" Destination/
done
```

This solution is worse when you want to descent directories:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Only sort Filenames.txt once
tmpSorted=/tmp/sortedFiles
sort Filenames.txt > ${tmpSorted}
# Go through directories
find . -type d | while read dir; do
      comm -23  <(ls -1 "${dir}" 2>/dev/null | sort) <(cat ${tmpSorted}) | while read file; do
         # remove the echo when it looks ok
         echo mv "${dir}"/"$file" Destination/
   done
done
rm ${tmpSorted}
```

Comment: Hmm, I've never seen `comm` before, that's cool. I'm hoping to do this recursively, so I'm not sure this would work.

Comment: That's an innovative way of handling the task, but it depends on certain filename formatting. Thanks for posting this, while it may not be a good solution, it's a great reminder of the diversity of tools that are available.